# Weird javascript behaviour FireFox 5.0

Tags: javascript, firefox-5

I've had a javascript running for quite som time and I've never experienced any problems in IE or in earlier version of firefox. In Firefox 5.0 however, if fails.

Note! The *formula* has been removed to simplify the example, as I've confirmed that the formula is working and producing the expected result.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function NaN(Num) {
        return (isNaN(Num) || Num == Infinity || Num == -Infinity ? "n/a" : Num);
    }

    function CalculateFormula() {
        result = NaN(*formula*);
    }

</script>
```

When the NaN function is to be called the javascript just exit. It works like a charm in IE, but to support FireFox 5.0 I've removed the NaN function from the result.

```
function CalculateFormula() {
    result = *formula*;
}
```

I've also tried this, but it also will exit from the script when calling the NaN function. But this confirmed that my formula returned a number as expected.

```
function CalculateFormula() {
    result = *formula*;
    result = NaN(result);
}
```

Anyone who can shed some light on this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's failing on Firefox because the [`NaN` property](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.1.1) of the global object is defined on ECMAScript 5 as *non-writable*, *non-configurable* and *non-enumerable*, and [Firefox 4 (and up)](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/) is implementing this version of the specification.

This means that the value of that property cannot be changed with an assignment *-non-writable-*, the property cannot be reconfigured (cannot change any of the three mentioned attributes) or being deleted *-non-configurable-*, and it will not appear on a `for-in` loop or with the `Object.keys` method *-non-enumerable-*.

You can rename your function or better yet, *restructure your code* in order to expose *less global identifiers* to avoid the problem.

Value properties of the global object as `NaN`, `Infinity` and `undefined`, were writable on ECMAScript 3, and this caused a lot of issues, you couldn't rely on its values, ES5 fixes the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Rename the function — [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) has now become a non-configurable property - so you just need to give your function another name

```
Error: can't redefine non-configurable property 'NaN'
Source File: formula.html
Line: 2
```

Comment: It isn't a reserved word, it's just a *non-writable* (non-configurable and non-enumerable) property of the global object.

Answer (score 2):

Try to redefine your `NaN` method with a different name, like `checkNaN`. It's a non-configurable global property.